ArcGIS Online field Maps Designer for migration doesn't work
I want to replicate the Field Maps Designer form to my new layer. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it properly.
I tried this way:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-maps/field-mobility/duplicate-maps-and-forms-for-use-in-field-maps/
But in turn, I am getting just a blank form without any fields and their types.

It looks like the JSON file doesn't cover the fields used in the form.
Is there any way for the replication such as this?
